# Convert curl command from google-colab to python script

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I have the following google colab code:

code :

```
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

LOG_DIR = './log'
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)

get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 6006 &')    
! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

output: 
https://6a112ff8.ngrok.io

My question is How do I convert the curl pipe python command (last 3 lines) into a python script ? Currently it is being executed in google colab.

I have tried to get close to solution using this code :

```
import sys, json
import requests
from IPython import get_ipython


LOG_DIR = './log'

get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)

response = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
# result=json.load(response)
print(json.load(response)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])
```

However I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system_raw'
```

Comment: here maybe https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: I tried your solution:  I get ''' import requests

response = requests.get('http://%7C')
''' I don't know how this would work when there is a curl command piped with python command

Comment: what value has import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])  ??

Comment: output: https://6a112ff8.ngrok.io "have No dashboards are active for the current data set."

Comment: There is no dashboard because I have not started the training process. I am trying to understand what the pipe command does in the above script and how can it be converted into nornal python ? I don't want a dependency on colab to run this small script

Comment: I don't understand much, but I think it can be that way.   https://pastebin.com/LMsbwPXs

Comment: Ive edited my question mentioning your solution, it takes me a step closer but Im unable to get the solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204258/discussion-between-giovanisalazar-and-ajinkya).

Comment: pls ,add the result of json.load(response) in your question

Comment: Ive created detailed question in another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340864/google-colab-ngrok-convert-to-python.  Please refer to new post for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @v25 comment I am able to run it using python. Here's what I understood.

**Warning**: On Macos there is some kind of permission issue with ngrok, hence I coudnt get the fist demo.py script running on macos. I got it running on Ubuntu 16

I downloaded these files and placed them in a folder where demo.py and demo2.py are present

```
wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
```

I made 2 scripts:

demo.py (nominal case)

```
import os
os.system('./ngrok http 8000 &')
```

for tensorboard replace os.system with:

```
os.system('tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 &'.format(LOG_DIR))
```

demo.py will run in one terminal window.

demo2.py

```
import os
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
    d = r.json() 
    public_url = d['tunnels'][0]['public_url']
    print(public_url)
except Exception as e:
    print ('Failed: ', e)
```

demo2.py will run in another terminal window.

demo2.py will produce a url which I can use. Please refer to v25's comment to see in details why 2 seperate terminal windows are needed. I am adding this solution for my future reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

To do this without curl in pure python, you could use the requests library, and the `json` method of the response object (`r` in this example) which returns a dictionary:

```
import requests
try:
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels')
    d = r.json() 
    public_url = d['tunnels'][0]['public_url']
except Exception as e:
    print ('Failed: ', e)

# Do something with `public_url`
```

Comment: How do I convert ```get_ipython().system_raw``` in python ?

Comment: Those commands are just running another program (tensorboard/ngrok) in the background.  Why not start these at a separate terminal, rather than trying to bundle them in a single script.  Also can you clarify what service is actually running on `localhost:4040`? I'm guessing this is some kind of ngrok service port, which gives you the public URL of the service (which by the way will change each time your run this script cause ngrok generates a new public URL on launch).  Stick this in a separate process somewhere and you'd have a more persistant URL.  Are you trying to run this on a local box?