# Google Colab ngrok convert to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I have a Google Colab notebook with following commands

```
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

LOG_DIR = './log'
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)
```

These commands run very well without any error in Google Colab . But when I run the same in python  get error.

Python demo.py

```
import sys, json
import requests
from IPython import get_ipython
import requests

LOG_DIR = './log'

get_ipython().system_raw(
    'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 &'
    .format(LOG_DIR)
)
```

ERROR: line 9: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'system_raw'

How do I resolve this error in python ?

Comment: What do you understand from the error message? Have you checked the value of `get_ipython`, done any debugging?

Comment: I would really appreciate if you point me to debugging get ipython.system.raw. I have researched on Google most of the literature I read is about google collab. Perhaps you know a better method for debugging which I have not yet tested. Please let me know  few pointers

Comment: Surely there is a way to do this without anything related to IPython? Can you explain what that code does/is meant to do?

Comment: The complete Google collab code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336142/convert-curl-command-from-google-colab-to-python-script?noredirect=1#comment104871234_59336142  this code logs machinelearning training process on tensorboard.

Comment: If you have access to google colab you can run the script in my previous comment . And observe that you get a url which will keep log of training process

Comment: if you try to `get_ipython()` then maybe you should run it with `ipython` - ie. `ipython demo.py`

Comment: I want to run it using ```python demo.py```

Comment: it seem you can't use `get_ipython()` with normal `python` because it doesn't run `ipython` automatically and `get_ipython()`  can't get it. There is `IPythom start_ipython()` but it runs `ipython` shell but then it wait for user command, not for command from file. You have to run it with `ipython`.

Comment: can't you use `os.system('tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 &'.format(LOG_DIR))`

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest trying something like `pyngrok` to programmatically manage your `ngrok` tunnel for you? Full disclosure, I am the developer of it. [Here are the](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest) docs if you're interest.

Comment: Life saver, awesome project dude.